# Prevent GitHub Action to run for each tag on a commit

Tags: github-actions

I have a publish workflow that is supposed to push the dists to PyPi if a commit on main is tagged with either frontend-v* or backend-v* (both are separate packages)

However, if a commit has changes on both the front- and backend and I add two tags to the commit, the workflow is triggered twice.

I understand that I could simply split the workflow into two, but I have another job that should run if either frontend or backend or both were updated which should only be ran once, thus I want to keep this in one workflow.

Can I somehow circumvent this to run this only once?

Thank you very much!

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    tags:
      - frontend*
      - backend*

jobs:
  backend:
    name: Publish backend
    if: ${{contains(github.ref_name, 'backend') }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
  frontend:
    name: Publish frontend
    if: ${{contains(github.ref_name, 'frontend') }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
  housekeeping: # this should only be ran once for the commit
    name: House Keeping
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
```